# storing for loop iteration data

Tags: python, storage, iteration

I am playing with cgi (uploading file form),

and I am receiving the files as storage object and I sotred it in (input) variable.

this is the simple iteration.

```
for file in input:
  filepath = ....
  filename, fileext = os.path.splitext(filepath)
  file_real_name = ....
  file_size = ....
  file_type = ...
  file_url = ....
  file_short_name = ...
  file_show_link = ....

  # etc
```

it would be easy if it was only one file ,  but what If i have more than one ?

how can I have another value that holds all the iteration information in

like `uploaded_files`  where I can access each uploaded file with all the information for the above iteration ?

I tried to read the docs but I cant wrap my head around some iteration concepts yet, sorry :)

Comment: @Alex Thank you , an example would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a data structure to hold your data. Depending on the complexity, you may want to simply use a list of dictionaries:

```
files = []
for file in input:
    files.append({
        "path": get_path(file),
        "name": get_name(file),
        "size": get_size(file),
        ...
    })
```

Or, if you find you need to perform lots of operations on your data, you might want to make your own class and make a list of objects:

```
class SomeFile:
    def __init__(self, path, name, size, ...):
        self.path = path
        ...

    def do_something_with_file(self):
        ...

files = []
for file in input:
    files.append(SomeFile(get_path(file), get_name(file), get_size(file), ...))
```

Note that here you are following a pattern of building up a list by iterating over an iterator. You can do this efficiently using a [list comprehension](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t85uBptTDYY), e.g:

```
[{"path": get_path(file), "name": get_name(file), ...} for file in input]
```

Also note that `file` and `input` are really bad variable names, as they will mask the builtins [`file()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#file) and [`input()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#input).

Comment: Thank you , is get_path() a method that I have to define ?

Comment: @static It's just placeholder code - you can place whatever code you want there to generate the values you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
results = []
for i in range(5):
    file_data = {}
    file_data['a'] = i
    file_data['b'] = i**2
    results.append(file_data)
print results
```